# Docker Quickstart Terminal unable to locate bash.exe

Tags: docker-for-windows

I have installed docker toolbox on Windows 7 64 bit machine. Installation showed a success message. However when i try to run a quick start terminal through shortcut created by installer is not working. It gives me an error

"Unable to locate bash.exe "

Comment: I got "Windows is searching for bash.exe".

Comment: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/335#issuecomment-164337300 might help

Answer (score 4):

It was a silly mistake. The default location with which the shortcut was created was pointing to 
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"

after i pointed the correct path of bash.exe, it stated working. 
C:\Softs\Git\bin\bash.exe --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"

Regards,
Vikrant Korde

Answer (score 1):

I had the error:

> Windows is searching for bash.exe

and was able to fix it by reinstalling Docker Toolbox with the Git option selected (I had unselected it on the first install).